# How to fix error Incompatible types "required string, found json array"

Tags: java, android, json

JSON:-

```
{
"events": ["wedding", "wed"],
"event_location": ["", ""],
"event_studio": [
    ["makeover", "epica", "Raddisson"],
    ["makeover", "epica"],
    ["Raddisson", "makeover", "contours"]
],
"event_studio_location": [
    ["Ernakulam", "thrissur", "kollam"],
    ["Ernakulam", "thrissur"],
    ["kollam", "Ernakulam", "Malappuram"]
]
}
```

Want to get events from json and store it in string array.

```
 String[] a=new String[responseBody.getJSONArray("events").length()];
 a=responseBody.getJSONArray("events");
```

Shows error Incompatible types required string found json array

Comment: a is string array and you are trying to assign JsonArray. That's why it gives error. You should try a[i]=responseBody.getJSONArray("events").toString();

Comment: ok i know,but i want to convert json array in to String array directly

Comment: You can use for loop for the same..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check JsonString Object is upcoming Json String , JsonObjct or JsonArray. Through `instanceof` and hold your JsonString in `JSONTokener`

like bellow code

```
Object object = new JSONTokener(jsonString).nextValue();

if (object instanceof JSONObject) 
{
  JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) object;
}
else  if (object instanceof JSONArray)
{
  JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) object;
}
```

Comment: "Check  JsonString Object is upcoming Json String , JsonObjct or JsonArray " what do u mean by this

Comment: We can hold String response in JsonTokenar and Check Json response root node is Array or Object same as applied in inner nodes one by one .

Comment: And when you find array then like other solutions you can cretae one for loop and get all Strings from JsonArray .

Answer (score 0):

You can't convert jsonarray to String array directly. You can convert jsonarray to String using this function:

```
public static String[] toStringArray(JSONArray array) {
if(array==null)
    return null;

String[] arr=new String[array.length()];
for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i]=array.optString(i);
}
return arr;
}
```

This will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

try below code

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("events");

        String[] arrayEvents=new String[jsonArray.length()];
        for(int i=0; i<arrayEvents.length; i++) {
            arrayEvents[i]=jsonArray.optString(i);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```